# How to install InquirerPy on Ubuntu 23.04 Lunar Loobster?

Tags: python, 23.04

I want to install InquirerPy python library on Ubuntu 23.04, but it isn't in repo. So I tried `pip install InquirerPy --break-system-package`. It installed, but then, when I wanted to use it, it can't find it. So I tried install it using venv. Same problem. Then, I tried pip3 and also, can't find it. So please help me.